# How to remove "document.execCommand("copy")" whitespaces and newlines?

Tags: javascript, html, select, clipboard

The code I'm creating is to copy a text once highlighted without touching the keyboard or right clicking on the text. Although I still want to remove whitespaces or new lines once it was been selected using regex. Although I'm not sure why this isn't working. Any help?

Javascript

```
var t = "";
function gText(e) {
  t = document.all
    ?document.selection.createRange().text
    : document.getSelection();
 document.execCommand("copy").value = t.replace(/\s+/g, '');
}

document.onmouseup = gText;
if (!document.all) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP);
```

Html

```
<p> Some of the text</p>

<p> <b>Some</b> of the text</p>
<p> <b>Some</b> of the text</p>

<table><tr><td>wew</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) `getSelection` when cast to string returns the text selected.

So need to use `toString()` or append a pair quotes to get the selected text

```js
var t = "";

function gText(e) {
  t = document.all ?
    document.selection.createRange().text :
    document.getSelection().toString();
  document.execCommand("copy").value = t.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  // for test only 
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = t.replace(/\s+/g, '');
}

document.onmouseup = gText;
if (!document.all) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP);
```

```html
<p> Some of the text</p>

<p> <b>Some</b> of the text</p>
<p> <b>Some</b> of the text</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>wew</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- test DOM -->
<div id="test"></div>
```